# What is the difference between dual-spin spacecraft and hybrid(attitude control) spacecraft?

Tags: orbital-maneuver, attitude, spin-stabilisation

The definition from this source is "Two classes of spacecraft bring together the advantages of having momentum bias and
yet provide a non-spinning base for accommodation of payload elements and torquers.
These are the dual-spin spacecraft and the hybrid spacecraft. In each case momentum bias
is provided by mounting a rotating body—or more than one—on the non-spinning part;
it is part of the structure in the case of the dual-spin spacecraft, but consists of high-speed
purpose-built wheels—momentum wheels—in the case of the hybrid spacecraft."

My interpretation for this is that for dual-spin spacecraft, its momentum basis is from a large slow rotating structure while for hybrid spacecraft, it is from a high speed momentum wheels? How does these 2 differ from pure spinner spacecraft? What is the distinguishing feature that define each of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your interpretation is correct. [*Galileo*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galileo_(spacecraft)) (Jupiter orbiter & probe) is an example of a dual-spin spacecraft. One large part of the spacecraft (structure and all) rotated, one part didn't, with a spin bearing between, and that's the distinguishing characteristic of the dual-spin method. On Galileo, instruments that wanted a spinning platform (magnetometer, charged particle detectors, etc.) were on the spinning part, and ones that wanted a 3-axis stable platform (camera, etc.) were on the non-spinning part. (I heard JPL engineers say, "Never again!" Apparently that spin bearing was a huge headache)

It appears multiple groups have adopted "hybrid" to describe their attitude control methods. For instance, one group applies it to [coupling thruster control with magnetic torque rods](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7569072/), some use it to [describe a control algorithm for controlling momentum wheels](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11771-016-3228-4). The momentum wheel method, which *doesn't* require that the spacecraft be spinning, requires a fair amount of electric power when precessing the momentum wheels, so for more rapid attitude changes they can design a thruster-based system in addition to the momentum wheels, making it a hybrid on multiple counts. The distinguishing characteristic of this type of control is that none of the spacecraft structure rotates except during attitude changes; all the rotation is within components dedicated to attitude control.

Some spacecraft, [*Cassini*](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.469.4018&rep=rep1&type=pdf) as an example, use reaction wheels instead of momentum wheels. They typically have thruster systems too, used sometimes for rapid attitude changes, sometimes for reaction wheel desaturation.

Comment: What about pure spinner? Is the difference between it and the hybrid is that only the latter has momentum bias?

Comment: A pure spinner is *completely* momentum-biased: every part of the spacecraft has angular momentum, so it's not a "hybrid". This is not the case with the dual-spin and momentum-wheel hybrid.

Comment: Another example of a NASA spacecraft with constant rotation is discussed in the question [How will GOES-R simultaneously point some instruments down at Earth and others sunward?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/19064/12102) though it's only 1 revolution per day in that case.