# When and when not to use the SDLS protocol?

Tags: flight-computer, protection

[image]When should the features provided by the Space Data Link Security Protocol ([SDLS](https://public.ccsds.org/Pubs/355x0b1.pdf)) be applied to [TM Data Space Link Protocol](https://public.ccsds.org/Pubs/132x0b2.pdf) communications?

This is with respect of ensuring protection within the layered architecture of TT&C (Telemetary, Tracking and Control) commands.

Comment: SDLS = Space Data Link Security

Comment: Welcome to the site! 
You might want to add an introductory sentence on your question since many people don't know what SDLS/Space Data Link Security is or is used for. something like 
"SDLS (Space Data Link Security) is a protocol used with ____, which is different from ___

Comment: I've tried to make the question clearer for you, without changing what was being asked. If I have accidentally changed the intent of your question @IeshaanSaxena, please change it to clarify your question.

Comment: @JCRM, yeah it seems fine, thank you!

Comment: that's a very useful diagram to include.

Comment: I felt so too, should've added it before!

Answer (score 1):

Being an old Cyber guy, but new to SpaceWire, I would think that SDLS features should be applied anytime security of the link is required ... SDLS provides authentication and encryption of the transmissions, so if these are important then SDLS protocol is probably the way to go.

Comment: [Why was SpaceWire designed with nine wires?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21572/12102)